# Play music and get user input simultaneously?

Tags: python, input, pygame

Can I get input and play music from pygame at the same time?

The code I have now:

```
from pygame import mixer

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('song.mp3')
mixer.music.play()

var = raw_input("Input: ")
print "you said ", var


while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)
```

It works fine until I enter something, and then the program stops:

```
Input: test
you said  test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "play.py", line 10, in <module>
    while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
NameError: name 'pygame' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from pygame import mixer
```

puts `mixer` in your namespace, but not `pygame`

You can either:

```
while mixer.music.get_busy():
```

or

```
import pygame
from pygame import mixer
```

importing `pygame` as well as it's subpackages you need is usually a good approach